# HTML Parsing with Python 2.7.10 - error with charmap

Tags: python, html, parsing

So now I'm trying to scrap websites using Python. I created a working code, but when I tried .prettify() or .get_text() method, it gave me that error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode character in position 32613-32614: character maps to <undefined>
```

The code looks like this:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.yellowpages.com/search?search_terms=Coffee+Shops&geo_location_terms=Los+Angeles%2C+CA"

r = urllib2.urlopen(url)


soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html5lib")

print soup.get_text()


g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "info"})

print "\nWell, those are our cofee shops:\n"

x=1
for item in g_data:
    try:
        if item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text != "Buy on eBay Today!":
            print "%d. %s\n" % (x, item.contents[0].find_all("a", {"class": "business-name"})[0].text)
        print "Adress: " + item.contents[1].find_all("p", {"class": "adr"})[0].text + "\n"
        x+=1
    except:
        pass
```

It works, when we comment/delete the line with `print soup.get_text()`

And I've tried lxml as well. If I don't set any parser, then it asks me to do so